# DDEV SSH to external ip

Tags: ddev

[EDIT]

I seem I cannot even SSH from DDEV to an external site. From within DDEV SSH:

`ssh -v bla@apiservice.nl`

`ssh: connect to host bla@apiservice.nl port 22: Cannot assign requested address 22`

[/EDIT]

What I really need is:

I want to make an SSH tunnel in DDEV to an external service.

On my Mac this works with `ssh -v -L 8080:xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080 bla@apiservice.xxx`

On DDEV I first do `ddev auth ssh`, I see the correct keys are there in `/var/www/html/.ssh`

Then `ddev exec ssh -v -L 8080:xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080 bla@apiservice.xxx`

Or `ddev exec ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pub -v -L 8080:xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080 bla@apiservice.xxx`

gives

```
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Debian-5+deb11u1, OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/jaccovanderpost/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to apiservice.xxx [yyy.yy.yy.yy] port 22.
ssh: connect to host apiservice.xxx port 22: Cannot assign requested address
```

Should an additional config in DDEV be made to map some ports or something?

Comment: If you can't *connect* ("Cannot assign requested address")then you have to start by solving the networking problem. Are you able to ping the hostname `apiservice.xxx` ? Can you `telnet <apiservice.xxx> 22` and get a connection? If not, you have to solve the network connectivity or name lookup problems first. If you're using Colima, please run it with `--dns 1.1.1.1`.

Comment: Ping I can do, but SSH not. I don't have telnet or Colima.

Comment: I'm asking you to do these things inside the ddev-webserver (`ddev ssh`).  The ddev-webserver has telnet and ping in it. `ddev ssh` and `telnet apiservice.xx 22` to see if you can connect. If you can't, you'll have to sort out the network connectivity problems you have. It certainly looks like you can't even connect to the service you're looking at. I was asking you to use ping inside the container also.

Comment: Ah yea of course. Ping works within ddev ssh, telnet hangs (trying).

Comment: If you can't `telnet <apiservicename> 22` then it means you don't have connectivity via tcp to the service, so it will not work.  Problems like this have been reported with latest version of Docker Desktop, which you seem to be using. 

It would be easier and faster to help you with this on Discord, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k